# Add space in between images

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, css-selectors

On my front page I have three posts in a row that are spread across the full width of the page. I want to add a padding of 30px to the left. However my problem is then that at the beginning of each row of images there is a padding of 30px.  I want it so that technical there is only a padding to the left and right 30px of the middle image, so the outer two images are always touching the end of the screen. I tried using :first-child to then take away the padding, however since I have the posts in a loop it did not work, and removed padding from all three images. Does anyone have a solution?

what it looks like...
[image]

```html
<article <?php post_class( 'col-md-4' ); ?>>
                <div class="front-thumbnail-image"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'medium-front-thumbnail')); ?></div></article>
```

```html
.medium-front-thumbnail {
    max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
     align-items: flex-end;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
.front-thumbnail-image {
    padding-left: 30px !important;
}

.col-md-4 {
    padding: 0 0 0 0 !important;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

my entire front-page.php

```html
<?php
/*
 * Template Name:
 */

get_header();
get_template_part ('inc/carousel');

$the_query = new WP_Query( [
    'posts_per_page' => 14,
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged', 1)
] );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { ?>
    <div id="ajax">
    <?php
    $i = 0;
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { $the_query->the_post();

        if ( $i % 7 === 0 ) { // Large post: on the first iteration and every 7th post after... ?>
        <article <?php post_class( 'col-md-12' ); ?>>
            <div class="large-front-container">
<?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'large-front-thumbnail')); ?>
                </div>
            <h2><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            <div class="front-post-info">
            <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                <?php get_template_part ('front-page-shop'); ?>
                                 <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
                <div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div>
            </article><?php

        } else { // Small posts ?>

            <article <?php post_class( 'col-md-4' ); ?>>
                <div class="front-thumbnail-image"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'medium-front-thumbnail')); ?></div>
                <a class="front-page-post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                <p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                <?php get_template_part ('front-page-shop'); ?>
                                 <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
                <div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div>
            </article>
            <?php
        }
        $i++;
    }?>
    </div>
    <?php if(get_query_var('paged') < $the_query->max_num_pages) {
       load_more_button();
    }
}
elseif (!get_query_var('paged') || get_query_var('paged') == '1') {
    echo '<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>';
}
wp_reset_postdata();
get_footer();
```

Comment: Can you provide more code of the structure, like the HTML part of your images?

Comment: I added my entire front page.php the images are then shown through the_post_thumbnail

Answer (score 1):

you can use `:nth-child(2)` to target the middle div.

```css
.grid > div:nth-child(2) {
  padding: 0 30px;
}


.grid > div {
  float: left;
}
.grid {
  background: red;
  overflow: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div><img src="https://www.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/10-dithering-opt.jpg"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/10-dithering-opt.jpg"></div>
  <div><img src="https://www.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/10-dithering-opt.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did nothing.

Comment: @user6738171 please provide a working demo of all of your code so that we don't waste ours and your time coming up with solutions that don't work for you.

Comment: how how could I make a working demo if everything is on a local host?

Comment: Your problem is just an issue with simple HTML and CSS. You can provide the relevant HTML and CSS on SO. If you need to include images, there are tons of places that will host them for free, like http://imgur.com, and you can reference those images in your SO post.

Answer (score 0):

On the code you've provided I can see you uses Flexbox. To the container of the images try to add `justify-content: space-between`. That should only add space between the images.

```css
.front-thumbnail-image {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<article class='col-md-4'>
  <div class="front-thumbnail-image">
    <img src="https://getuikit.com/v2/docs/images/placeholder_600x400.svg" height="120" />
    <img src="https://getuikit.com/v2/docs/images/placeholder_600x400.svg" height="120" />
    <img src="https://getuikit.com/v2/docs/images/placeholder_600x400.svg" height="120" />
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
.grid img:not(:first-child) , .grid img:not(:last-child) {
     padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
```

**Full code :**

```css
img {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
}
.grid {
      background-color: red;
      display: inline-block;
}
.grid img:not(:first-child) , .grid img:not(:last-child) {
      padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
            <img src="http://cdn.earthporm.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/animal-family-portraits-2__880.jpg">
            <img src="http://onehdwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Abdorble-Animals-Desktop-Wallpapers-Pictures.jpg">
            <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/b2/1e/c9/b21ec91754d33bb5de86c67c45482e12.jpg">
            <img src="http://cisnerosnediadistribution.s3.amazonaws.com/media/images/reino_animal_-_trailer_image.png">
            
</div>
```